# Where do C and POSIX specify that standard headers have to be included at file scope?

Tags: c, posix, language-lawyer

I just dealt tangentially with a bug report where a piece of software was incorrectly doing `#include <sched.h>` inside the body of a function, and I was unable to find authoritative text stating that this is not valid usage. The closest I could find, for the standard C headers, is 7.1.2 ¶4:

> If used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, ...

but it's not even entirely clear to me how this should be interpreted, and of course it doesn't cover POSIX-only headers like `sched.h`.

It's clear from the text just before the above:

> Standard headers may be included in any order; each may be included more than once in a given scope, with no effect different from being included only once, ...

that no implementation using the standard approach to multiple inclusion guards could satisfy that requirement if inclusion in block scope were permitted, but I'd like to see something more clear, and something in POSIX.

Comment: Inside a function is not "outside of any external declaration or definition" (a function definition is an external definition) , that part seems reasonably clear for the Standard C headers

Comment: Why do you need a POSIX source if the C standard quote you give already gives a general requirement? POSIX standards supplement the C standards here, right, they don't relax the existing C standards? If it doesn't follow C standards, it's not C, so some "obeys POSIX, ignores C" thing isn't C, and could presumably do whatever it wanted, but it's irrelevant to programming in C.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: C 2018 7.1.2 4 specifies rules for the C standard headers. It does not apply to POSIX headers. Even if POSIX supplements C, that does not mean the headers of POSIX become C standard headers covered by 7.1.2 4. POSIX could deal with that in a variety of ways, such as by stating that use of its headers shall be subject to the rules for C standard headers, or that its headers shall be included only outside of any external declaration or definition.

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, I should have looked up what "external declaration or definition" is defined as. But the POSIX part is still open.

Comment: If it turns out this text is simply missing from POSIX I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear on the wording of the clauses quoted below, recall that `external declaration` is defined in the C grammar (§6.9, *External Definitions*)

```
translation-unit:
    external-declaration
    translation-unit external-declaration
external-declaration:
    function-definition
    declaration
```

So the program text ("translation unit") is just a series of external definitions. This has nothing to do with the use of the word "external" in "external linkage". As noted in paragraph 4 of that section:

> …the unit of program text after preprocessing is a translation unit, which consists of a sequence of external declarations. These are described as “external” because they appear outside any function (and hence have file scope).

Consequently, the restriction in §7.1.2¶4 quoted in the question applies to any declaration or definition at file scope. (I don't know why the standard says "external declaration *or definition*", since the set of external definitions are a subset of external declarations. But I don't see how that phrase can be read to exclude any external declaration, even one which happens not to be a definition.)

In Posix, essentially the same restriction appears in System Interfaces Chapter 2 (General Information), at the end of section 2.2 (the Compilation Environment):

> If used, the application shall ensure that a header is included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it shall be first included before the first reference to any type or macro it defines, or to any function or object it declares. However, if an identifier is declared or defined in more than one header, the second and subsequent associated headers may be included after the initial reference to the identifier. Prior to the inclusion of a header, the application shall not define any macros with names lexically identical to symbols defined by that header.

Link:

- [The Compilation Environment](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02). The quoted text appears at the end of that section, so you could find it more easily by going to the [next section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_03) and scrolling up a couple of paragraphs.

Comment: Hm. Is `static void f(void) { ... }` an "external declaration or definition". If not, wouldn't it then be legal to write `static void f(void) { \n #include <sched.h> \n }`?

Comment: @pipe: it's an external declaration and an external definition of a function with internal linkage. I'll add the definition of external declaration to the answer.

Comment: Yes, the use of the word "external" here is very misleading; it has different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: @R..: like `const` :-) But the word "external" is  never used in the standard as a noun, only as an adjective. And adjectives always modify something. It's normal for the meaning of an adjective to vary based on what it modifies. (Although I agree that standard language, like legal language, is full of traps for the unwary.)